# Post to url but stay on page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I built this link:

```
<a href=""#"" onclick=""this.href='test.asp?Code=123&ReturnTo=test2.asp'; testfunction(this, event); return true;"">
```

The problem is it sends the user to the link rather than staying on the page, posting to the url and executing the function. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Ajax to send data to an url. Ajax is using every where for this purpose. If u are interest in Jquery follow this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You are using double double quotes for the attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what do you want to do?

Typically if you want to make a request but not navigate, you use an XmlHttpRequest (xhr).

The technique is called AJAX, for Asynchronous Javascript And Xml, but most apps use json instead of xml.

You can fire an xhr from anchor tags, but you need to put a click event handler on the anchor, stop event propagation and return false from the handler to stop the browser from navigating.

Comment: I want it to keep the user on the page they're on rather than redirecting them.

Comment: do you mean you want the new page to open in the same window?

Comment: No, I want nothing to change, just post to that url and then execute that function.

Comment: then i think you want to use an xhr